# ExtJS upgrade Nightmare 4.2.2 to 5.1 (Associations not working!!)

Tags: extjs, model, synchronization, associations, upgrade

I have a bunch of association working great in 4.2.2 which have now stopped working in my upgrade to version 5.1 (Compatibility mode is off on purpose)

```
    Ext.define('BA.model.Betas', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'id',
        type : 'number',
        useNull : true
    }, {
        name : 'betaName',
        type : 'string'
    },
    ....
     ],
    belongsTo : [ {
        name : 'model',
        model : 'BA.model.Models',
        associationKey : 'betas',
        getterName : 'getModel',
        setterName : 'setModel'
    } ],
    hasMany : [ {
        name : 'securities',
        model : 'BA.model.Securities',
        primaryKey : 'id',
        foreignKey : 'fk'
    }, {
        name : 'mappingVOs',
        model : 'BA.model.Portfolios',
        primaryKey : 'relId',
        foreignKey : 'fk'
    }, {
        name : 'params',
        model : 'BA.model.Params',
        primaryKey : 'name' + 'group',
        foreignKey : 'fk'
    } ],
    idProperty : 'id'
});
```

When I was doing store.sync() in 4.2.2, the entire tree structure was going to the server:

```
[
  {
    "id": 199034,
    "betaName": "DUVACFEF",
    "betaDesc": "DUVACFEF",
    "region": "GLOBAL",
    "sequencer": "",
    "securities": [data],
    "mappingVOs": [data],
    "params": [data]
  }
]
```

But after the upgrade to ExtJS 5.1, this is going:

```
[
  {
    "id": 199034,
    "betaName": "DUVACFEF",
    "betaDesc": "DUVACFEF",
    "region": "GLOBAL",
    "sequencer": "",
```

> "fk": null

```
  }
]
```

Please help. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.data.writer.Json.override({
    /*
     * This function overrides the default implementation of json writer. Any
     * hasMany relationships will be submitted as nested objects. When preparing
     * the data, only children which have been newly created, modified or marked
     * for deletion will be added. To do this, a depth first bottom -> up
     * recursive technique was used.
     */
    getRecordData : function(record) {
        return record.getData({
            associated : true
        });
    }
});
```